# Architecture for a mobile application

Tags: cordova, mobile, mobile-application

I have never written a mobile app , planning to write one now. Need advice on architecture of same.

Let me first brief on the functionality :

- Its a kind of "General Knowledge Ques & Ans" application.
- There will be different categories & in each category there will be different questions.
- User can scroll through all questions in a category (using Next or Back button) ,
- For each question there is a "show answer" button , after user has thought of answer can check the same using the button.

something like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.programmerworld.HRInterviewQuestionsLite&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5wcm9ncmFtbWVyd29ybGQuSFJJbnRlcnZpZXdRdWVzdGlvbnNMaXRlIl0.

Other features
1. should work on all platforms (androids , ios , windows mobile , etc ) hence planning to use phonegap

1. The list of Q&A should be up-datable , like i can give updates having totally new Q&A , or better ans to old questions , or new categories etc
2. The Q&A should be non copyable , like if someone installs the app on his mobile , he should not be able to copy the Q&A list
3. The Q&A list should be stored securely on the mobile
4. allow users to bookmark some ques and later go through only the bookmarked lists

Planning to use PhoneGap for it. What i am not sure is how to "best" store the Q&A Data securely and efficiently so that my app is not very heavy also ???

I am aware of two options

1) Android SQLLite .. if i use this i am sure its secure , and easily updatable BUT i am not sure what to do for iOS and other operating system ? is there a cross platform SQL engine ? wont this be heavy ? i mean every user who wants to use my app would need to install this as well

2) cant i store the Q&A as encrypted xml files ?? this way it should be easily updatable and what algo should i use for encryption ? will it be safe enough ?? any cross platform library implementing encryption algorithm ?

3) any other suggestions by experts out there ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is to retrieve the q&a from a remote server. You can make a server that offer an API, so that the app can make an ajax request through this API to get the data.

Comment: hmmmm ... pretty neat , why that didnt occur to me before ... one more ques here i hope this will not be slow ... i have 2 options here 1) get one Q&A at a time as and when user presses next or back get another one          2) get 3 at a time present ques , next ques and previous , as and when user presses next or back get one more

Comment: imo, request a couple a Q&A at once seems the correct way to do it, since you will reduce the latency caused by those requests and waiting for response.

Answer (score 0):

still looking for more approaches , i am more interested in an approach where user can install once and use anywhere (even offline) with or without internet

Comment: You can store the questions in the localStorage. This should be usable  in all devices.